# gojs seating chart - seat a guest by code

Tags: javascript, gojs

I'm using this example: https://gojs.net/latest/samples/seatingChart.html
[image]
We can seat a 'guest' by drag and drop events.
However, I want to occupy a seat by code (create a node then seat a guest by code), with input is an object { id: "001",  name: "Arya Stark", table : 3, seat: 1 }

How to do that?

Thanks you!

Comment: What have you tried already and what issues did you run into?  Please share existing code with us here

Comment: @Deryck I took a look at function assignPeopleToSeats(node, coll, pt). I think that need to create a node with an object { id: "001", name: "Arya Stark", table : 3, seat: 1 }. However, I don't know how to create 'node' or 'coll, pt' from where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but maybe:

```
var newguest = { key:"Arya Stark", table:3, seat:1 };
myDiagram.model.commit(function(m) {
    m.addNodeData(newguest);
    positionPersonAtSeat(newguest);
}, "added guest");
```

Comment: I tried but show me an error: "Uncaught TypeError: myDiagram.model.commit is not a function"

Comment: Use version 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

I tried these, and they worked:

```
var newguest = { key:"Arya Stark", table:3, seat:1 };

var table=myDiagram.findNodeForKey(newguest.table);
var point=null;
for(const sit=table.elements;sit.next();){
    const seat=sit.value;
    if(sit.name==newguest.seat){
        point=seat.getDocumentPoint(go.Spot.Center);
        break;
    }
}
myDiaram.model.addNodeData(newguest);
var guest=myGuest.findNodeForKey(newguest.key);
guest.isSelected=true;
assignPeopleToSeats(table,myDiaram.selection,point);
guest.isSelected=false;
```

Or you can save myGuests.model as a json, so that you can save the location of tables and guests.
Besides, you can add some code in the function positionPersonAtSeats(), to save the correct location:

```
positionPersonAtSeats(guest){
    ...
    const loc=seat.getDocumentPoint(go.Spot.Center);
    ...
    guest.loc=loc.x+' '+loc.y;
}
```